# Android: ListView with Search functionality and checkBox

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have implemented a listView with search functionality and checkBox. The problem is once I search from editText,once searched text is selected its taking the value from original listView and I am not getting the exact value what I want.

I found some solutions online but did not work. Please help me.

**activity_invitecaretaker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button_invite">
        </ListView>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:hint="@string/search_caretaker"
                  android:inputType="text"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  style="@style/EditTextCustomHolo"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/cancel_text"
                android:text="@string/cancel_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputSearch"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/send_invite"
                android:id="@+id/button_invite"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/android:list"                />
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/skip_button"
                android:id="@+id/button_skip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/android:list"                   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_example_entry.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <CheckedTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email_entry"/>
        <CheckedTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/phone_entry"/>

        <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_listview"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.OperationApplicationException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;



/**
 * Created by on 2015-10-15.
 */

public class InviteCaretakers extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private EditText inputSearch;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private EditText edit;
    private Button skipButton;
    private Button inviteButton;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private Boolean test;
    private String email;
    private CheckBox cb;
    private ListView lv ;
    private TextView emailId;
    private String  emailOrg;
    private String searchStr;
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> checkedList;
    private ArrayList<String> arraySort= new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> checkedcontacts;
    private MyAdapter ma ;
    private int EL_Length;
    ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    final DeviceUtil deviceUtil=new DeviceUtil();
    final String TAG = InviteCaretakers.class.getName();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invitecaretaker);

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        searchStr = inputSearch.getText().toString();

        skipButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
        skipButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent RemindInviteIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RemindInvite.class);
                startActivity(RemindInviteIntent);
            }
        });

        getEmailContact();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        doSearch();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_example_entry, R.id.email_entry, emailList);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)skipButton.getLayoutParams();
        skipButton.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (deviceUtil.getScreenWidth(getApplicationContext())) * 53 / 100;
        skipButton.setLayoutParams(params);

        inviteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_invite);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)inviteButton.getLayoutParams();
        inviteButton.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (deviceUtil.getScreenWidth(getApplicationContext())) / 2;
        inviteButton.setLayoutParams(params1);

        //if checked status is true add to array thats-it
        checkedcontacts = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("no of checked boxes..." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
        System.out.println("FINALOUT checkedlist EMAILList" + checkedcontacts);
        int count = checkedcontacts.size();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected" + String.valueOf(ma.mCheckStates.size()) + "contacts!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //onclick of invite button- get count & value of radio
        inviteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                //StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
                checkedcontacts = new ArrayList<String>();
                System.out.println("no of checked boxes..." + ma.mCheckStates.size());

                if ( ma.mCheckStates.size() != 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < emailList.size(); i++) {
                        test   = ma.mCheckStates.get(i);
                        System.out.println("test......" + test);

                        if (test == true){
                            checkedcontacts.add(emailList.get(i).toString());
                            String email= emailList.get(i).toString();
                            System.out.println("Checked......" + emailList.get(i).toString());
                            getEmail();
                            checkedcontacts.addAll(arraySort);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //
            }
        });

        //onclick of invite button- get count & value of radio
        cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_text);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                inputSearch.setText("");
            }
        });
    } //oncreate


    public void getEmail(){

        System.out.println("FINAL-OUT CHECKED ARRAY" + checkedcontacts);
        int count = checkedcontacts.size();
        System.out.println("count"+count);
        for (int j = 0; j < checkedcontacts.size(); j++) {
            email= checkedcontacts.get(j).toString();
            System.out.println("email inString" + email);
            //if (!email.isEmpty()){
            Pack pack = PackManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).activePack();
            System.out.println("pack in inviteCare"+pack);

            PackManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).inviteCareTakers(pack, email, new OnServerResponseListener<String, String>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String successParam) {

                    PackManager.getInstance(InviteCaretakers.this);
                    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(InviteCaretakers.this, com.synclabs.dogsync.members.InviteSent.class);
                    InviteCaretakers.this.startActivity(intent);

                    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS inside inviteCareTakers");
                    getEmail();
                        for (int j = 1; j < checkedcontacts.size(); j++) {
                            email = checkedcontacts.get(j).toString();
                            System.out.println("email inside onSuccess" + email);

                        }
                    getEmail();
                    //finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String failureParam) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "failure inside inviteCareTakers");
                }
            });
        } // for
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    //from device contacts extract email Id's
    public ArrayList<String> getEmailContact() {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email INVITE", email);

                    //check if emailList already contains, if not there then add else don't add to list
                    if (!emailList.contains(email)) {
                        emailList.add(email);
                    }
                }
                cur1.close();
            }
            Log.e("EmailList INVITE1", String.valueOf(emailList));
            EL_Length = emailList.size();
            Log.e("length of arrayList", String.valueOf(EL_Length));

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_example_entry, R.id.email_entry, emailList);

        }

        return emailList;
    }

    public void addToList() {

        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        if (edit != null ) {
            emailList.add(edit.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            int rawContactID = ops.size();

            // Adding insert operation to operations list
            // to insert a new raw contact in the table ContactsContract.RawContacts
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                    .build());

            // Adding insert operation to operations list
            // to insert Home Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, edit.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());

            try {
                // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void doSearch() {

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                searchStr = inputSearch.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("searchStr inside onTextChanged"+ searchStr);
                arraySort.clear();

                int textlength = inputSearch.getText().length();

                for (int i = 0; i < emailList.size(); i++) {
                    if (textlength <= emailList.get(i).length()) {
                        if (inputSearch.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase
                                ((String) emailList.get(i).subSequence(0, textlength))) {


                            //get the index of value in new array_sort and store it in a variable for check
                            System.out.println("EmailList index" + emailList.indexOf(emailList.get(i).toString()));
                            emailOrg = emailList.get(i).toString();
                            System.out.println("emailOrg" + emailOrg);
                            arraySort.add(emailOrg);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //this is needed for searching through
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InviteCaretakers.this, R.layout.list_example_entry, R.id.email_entry, emailList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //

                // not existing = add to array and list call if it matches email id structure
                Validation va = new Validation();
                if (va.isValidEmailId(searchStr)) {
                    getEmailContact();
                    addToList();
                    Log.e("length EL AFTER ADDING", String.valueOf(EL_Length));
                }
                System.out.println("array_sort items" + arraySort);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    //
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        CheckBox cb;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(emailList.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)InviteCaretakers.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return emailList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;

            if(convertView==null)

                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_example_entry, null);

            TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.email_entry);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_listview);

            tv.setText(emailList.get(position));

            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }
        public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
            System.out.println("hello...........");
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your layout & adapter code to your question?

Comment: How is the checkbox related to the problem? What is the list item and how do you perform search? More code or layouts and explanation, please...

Comment: I am trying to add the code, and formatted code as well but it says I have not formatted and not allowing me to submit Post. How do i do that . Please  could you tell me.

Comment: No need of formatting, just add the code.

Comment: Can you pl explain what you mean by "its taking the value from original listView and I am not getting the exact value what I want."

Comment: Original listView as in I mean like the listView before searching. Once the search String is entered in search editText, the value taken is the first item from listView. For e.g. i have A B C in list and i search for C through editText, I get the value A. its not getting me the actual value after search. it is getting the values based on  position. This is the problem.

Comment: Added the java code to the question. It have got saved inside list_example_entry.xml

Comment: @papi did you get what you want?